# MySQL Basic query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have managed to get a result that says full_name and facility_name.
Here the facility names consists of "Tennis Court1","Tennis Court2","Squash Court", "Badminton" and "Table Tennis"

I now want to filter and present by only "Tennis Court"

I have tried adding

`WHERE facility_name ILIKE '%Tennis Court%`

but get an error that says:
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ILIKE '%Tennis%' at line 15

```
    SELECT 
    DISTINCT(CONCAT(z.firstname,' ', z.surname)) AS full_name,
    facilities.name AS facility_name

FROM
    (SELECT members.memid, 
        bookings.facid, 
        members.firstname, 
        members.surname
        FROM Members AS members
        RIGHT JOIN Bookings AS bookings
        ON members.memid =bookings.memid) z
RIGHT JOIN Facilities as facilities
    ON facilities.facid = z.facid
WHERE facility_name LIKE 'Tennis Court%'
```

Here are the links to the table.
[TABLES used in the SQL query](https://easyupload.io/ln1x7i)

The error : #1054 - Unknown column 'facility_name' in 'where clause'. Just to inform you. There are 2 facility names 'Tennis Court1' and 'Tennis Court2'

Comment: Note that DISTINCT is not a function, and nobody ever uses RIGHT JOIN. Also, this isn't the query that generated that error

Comment: @Strawberry `SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(z.firstname,' ', z.surname) AS full_name, facilities.name as facility_name FROM (SELECT members.memid, bookings.facid, members.firstname, members.surname FROM Members AS members RIGHT JOIN Bookings AS bookings ON members.memid =bookings.memid) z RIGHT JOIN Facilities as facilities ON facilities.facid = z.facid WHERE facility_name LIKE 'Tennis Court%' `This gives me the error : #1054 - Unknown column 'facility_name' in 'where clause'. Just to inform you. There are 2 facility names 'Tennis Court1' and 'Tennis Court2'

Comment: If you use full value as a filter then use direct compare `=` instead of LIKE operator. `WHERE facility_name = 'Tennis Court'`.

Comment: Please edit your question accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Replace `ILIKE` TO `LIKE` in your query and remove brackets after `distinct` as `distinct` is not a function

Comment: Himanshu. noted. `SELECT 
 DISTINCT CONCAT(z.firstname,' ', z.surname) AS full_name,
 facilities.name as facility_name

FROM
 (SELECT members.memid, 
  bookings.facid, 
  members.firstname, 
  members.surname
  FROM Members AS members
  RIGHT JOIN Bookings AS bookings
  ON members.memid =bookings.memid) z
RIGHT JOIN Facilities as facilities
 ON facilities.facid = z.facid

WHERE facility_name LIKE 'Tennis Court%'` This gives me the error : #1054 - Unknown column 'facility_name' in 'where clause'. Just to inform you. There are 2 facility names 'Tennis Court1' and 'Tennis Court2'

Answer (score 0):

Incidentally, your query appears to be functionally identical to:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT_WS(' ',m.firstname,m.surname) full_name
              , f.name facility_name 
           FROM facilities f
           JOIN bookings b
             ON b.facid = f.facid
           LEFT 
           JOIN members m
             ON m.memid = b.memid
          WHERE f.name LIKE 'Tennis Court%'
```

And, if I'm wrong, see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much
I used facid instead of facility_name

The code goes as follows:

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT CONCAT(z.firstname,' ', z.surname) AS full_name,
    facilities.name as facility_name

FROM
    (SELECT members.memid, 
        bookings.facid, 
        members.firstname, 
        members.surname
        FROM Members AS members
        RIGHT JOIN Bookings AS bookings
        ON members.memid =bookings.memid) z
RIGHT JOIN Facilities as facilities
    ON facilities.facid = z.facid

WHERE facilities.facid=0 OR facilities.facid=1
```